# Handle unexpected character in DocuSign API envelopes

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

On the situations where DocuSign envelopes get automatically created through API, what is the best practice over unexpected characters? I have situations where through the night someone's envelope contains texts with `<0x0B>` and that breaks the DocuSign Connect and causes that DocuSign Status record not getting created in Salesforce just because the unexpected character or a hexadecimal value is in one of the envelope data fields.

What are some references to use in order to know all these unexpected characters and maybe set up a way to block making the API call when one of them is present? OR  is there a way to force update the envelope to remove those unexpected character(S)?

Connect Failure Log shows an error like below:

```
https://na2.docusign.net/Member/SFIntegration.aspx :: Error - '', hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 11539.
```

**Update:** Just realized the unexpected character is hidden in the post. Here is the character that causes the failure. Notice the hexadecimal character between the words:

[image: hexadecimal character]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the error is in the SFIntegration.aspx code that receives the Connect notification, not in the Connect webhook system itself.

Connect should be able to handle any characters in an envelope. If not, then there is a bug.

Where was this rogue character? In the envelope's email subject line? Somewhere else?

Thank you.

Comment: This happens in the value of a "textTab". Users often copy/paste value from a pdf to the form and the input in that textTab includes a <0x0B>. Just realized Stackoverflow hide the value so I just updated the post and included a picture of the unexpected character.